# Removing items from a Hashmap that DOESN'T have a specific value

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Hashmap<ArrayList, Integer>. The keys are an integer list containing b and c in this equation

> a = n*b+c

and the value is a. I only want the keys (a,b) that give me a specific value of a, for example 3. I am aware of how to remove key/value pairs using a value, but I need help doing the opposite. I want to keep all the key/value pairs that has the same value

```
a.map.entrySet().removeIf(entries -> entries.getValue() == a);
```

Basically, is there a way to say something like

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(entries -> entries.getValue() != a);
```

Comment: I don't follow. E.g. if you want to remove entries whose value is != 3, just do it: `map.entrySet().removeIf(entries -> !entries.getValue().equals(3))`. Any boolean condition will do it

Comment: Yeah, this was the solution. I just didn't know the syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You already have it. `map.entrySet().removeIf(entries -> entries.getValue() != a)` already works. (Though you might have to use `!entries.getValue().equals(a)` instead.)

Comment: I get "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface". when trying this